# Можно ли в ASP.net 2.0 сделать поиск по первым буквам в комбобоксе

Tags: c#, list, asp.net

Вопрос: Можно ли в ASP.net 2.0 сделать поиск по списку как в гугле...

То есть вводим первые буквы, а он отображает подходящие варианты. Сейчас реализовано с помощью `DropDownList`. Как я понимаю в Asp да и ещё таком старом нет такого функционала. Возможно можно как-то выйти из ситуации не переписывая весь код на MVC или core код DropDownList:

```
<td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="AttributesDropDownList" DataSourceID="AttributeNamesDataSource" DataTextField="attrName" DataValueField="id" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
         <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True">Не используется в фильтре</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

Список берётся из базы данных

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/combobox/how-do-i-use-the-combobox-control-cs ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231387/asp-net-auto-complete-dropdownlist

Comment: Спасибо, данная ссылка помогла